Looking to improve searches across large ( 7-10 GB files )
I have a need to search for many ( thousands) of dns within a large ( 7-10 GB) ldif file and print out the entries after it . I am mostly familiar with shell/python so tried to use awk for this and it works but it is a bit slow.
I use a counter when it finds a matching line - print everything under there and reset back to 0 if the line doesn't start with dn.
I can't use grep -A because each entry can contain different number of lines to be printed .
I don't have the means to import this into another ldap/db with indexing..just looking for something quick that I can use for now .
if anyone knows any Linux-fu that can help please let me know!
sorry I meant like the dn: pattern in an ldif file. For clarity - here is what I want
I have a file with -
dn: pattern1
phone: xxxx 
email: yyyy

dn: pattern2 
phone: xxxx
email: yyy

I have the dn: pattern that needs to be searched and the lines below that to be printed - till it reaches the next line with dn:
. There is one empty line between entries.
This is my code so far
awk -v dn="$dn" '
    BEGIN { counter = 0 }
    {
        if ($0 ~ /^dn: /) {
            if ($0 == dn) {
                counter = 1
            } else if (counter) {
                exit
            }
        }
        if (counter) {
            print
        }
    }
    '


(1) What do you mean by “dns”?  (2) It’s not clear to me what you want, or why you can’t use grep -A.  (3) We generally (automatically) ask people to show what they’ve tried.  If you have an awk command that gives you the output you want, then posting that kills two birds with one stone, as it will clarify what you want.  …  …  …  …  …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

"There is one empty line between entries." Does a blank line like that appear anywhere else? Inside an entry? If no, you can use that as the record separator, newline as the FS and check the first field directly for the whole record. Something like: awk -v RS='\n\n' -F '\n' -v dn="$dn" '$1 == dn'

The "obvious" way to go about searching in LDIF – that's LDAP Data Interchange Format – is to load that data into an LDAP instance and then query that. In fact, that's the way it's meant to be handled!
So, simply do that. OpenLDAP is not very hard to install on any Linux distro, and if you need the isolation, running one of the many OpenLDAP docker images that you find on hub.docker.com works.
You can load an LDIF file into your (temporary) LDAP server like this:
slapadd -f /etc/ldap/slapd.conf -l /path/to/data.ldif

The advantage of docker containers would be that you can run as many LDAP servers in parallel as you want, without having to change ports in their configuration.
Clearly, OpenLDAP is much much faster than awk when it comes to searching for things.

yes I did approach a restore using ldap as the first option but limited to some privacy issues with data and need to follow some procedures etc which will take more time than the script itself - I left it running in the background for now. Was just looking if there is some cool command that I am missing :( Thanks for your help !

the privacy issues are there as soon as you get the LDIF file. the way you parse it with is fully irrelevant to privacy. It's what you do with the data; make sure your data protection officer is on board with what you're doing, and not how you're doing it. I don't really know what to tell you – setting up an openldap container (i.e., pulling the image from dockerhub) takes literal seconds, and I remember imports into OpenLDAP to be fast, so, I really don't think there's anything we can help you with it you're punting any solution based on mostly unfounded "privacy concerns".

You could try pcre2grep (formerly pcregrep) in multiline mode:
$ dn='dn: pattern1'
$ pcre2grep -M "^\Q$dn\E\n(?:(?!dn:).+\n)*" file.ldif
dn: pattern1
phone: xxxx
email: yyyy

Which prints sequences of lines starting with the $dn one and all the following ones that don't start with dn:.
Here since the entries are delimited by empty lines, you can use perl's or awk's paragraph mode.
dn: pattern1
phone: xxxx
email: yyyy

$ DN=$dn awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'BEGIN{dn = ENVIRON["DN"]}; $1 == dn' file.ldif
dn: pattern1
phone: xxxx
email: yyyy

Note that in general, you don't want to use -v to pass arbitrary data to awk as it mangles backslash characters in those.
With the pcre2grep or awk approaches, changing the locale to C (with LC_ALL=C awk...) might speed things up as it would save doing some potentially costly (and unneeded here) character decoding. No needed in perl which doesn't do locale-based character decoding by default.

Your file is so small it fits in memory.
In that case I will suggest you write a small tool that does your search and parallelize it: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions
mytool() {
    # Read stuff on stdin and grep the right lines
    # Maybe awk works better for you?
    # file_with_dns.txt contains all dns to look for
    perl -e '$/=undef; $dn = <>; shift; $re=join"|",split/\n/,$dn; $/="\n\n"; while(<STDIN>){ /dn: ($re)/ and print; }' file_with_dns.txt
}
export -f mytool

parallel --pipepart big10G.file --block -3 --recend '\n\n' mytool


If your data is as simple and consistent as the sample in your question, you can get away with a short awk command to pull out your intended block (say,for pattern2):
awk '/^dn/{f=(/pattern2/)} f' input.txt
dn: pattern2 
phone: xxxx
email: yyy

